# Best practice when sending multiple pictures via REST

Tags: android, rest

I'm finishing an app that, at a given moment, has to send several pictures to a server via REST.

The code I've made send them one by one using a MultipartEntity.

It works, but seems to be a bit slow. Another problem is if some photo is not sent, how can I handle the pictures that were sent.

Is this the best practice for this? Do you know a better way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: What do you use to send the pictures to your REST service? Do you use a background thread? I would recommend using a service for this to ensure images are still uploaded even when the user exits your app. If an image fails to send, you should receive an error message. If you receive an error message, move that picture to the back of your upload queue and try again later.

Comment: Also what does "seem a bit slow" means? Most networks does not have a lot of upload speed compared to download speed, which is why uploading something as big as a picture might seem time consuming compared to downloading images.

Comment: Yes, I'm using an AsyncTask to send each picture. I was wondering if is there anyway to "group" all the pictures and send them with just one call. This would save me the word of checking all the results.

Comment: Seems a bit slow due to the fact that I have to make several calls to the server. Even the progress dialog seems to freeze a lot of times. It is not related to the speed of the upload, but the user experience.

Comment: This seems to be the best way to do it, so?

Comment: Well I recommend to use Service for it with CPU wake lock to ensure the process is completed 100% and after job done call destructor to save battery juice by releasing wake lock

Comment: There is a really nice way to reduce problems related to sending failure. Thanks!